# Should I use a ConfigParser directly in my code?

Tags: python, configparser

I hope there is a 'right' answer to this:

When using `ConfigParser` to manage default values in a .cfg or .ini file, should I copy everything I need to program variables and copy them back out on exit, or should I use the `config.get(section, option)` directly in my program as needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a matter of opinion, but my advice is to have the values out of the config relatively quickly. The code that deals with data input and the layer that deals with the actual processing should be modular enough that you can change your data source by just feeding in data from a different source. (Coupling and Cohesion)

You'll have to use your own judgement to make the call as to where to draw the line, but as a guide: if you're setting the config as a global variable and reading from there or constantly throwing it around as an argument, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I was making it a bound variable of a session object, but after reading your answer I realize I should probably set up `@property` getters for my session class that use a `_load_default(x)` function which happens to read from a config but could be changed. Great answer, thanks.